# Error "Detecting Library Folders" in Zend Studio

Tags: php, eclipse, git, zend-framework, zend-studio

I just had to re-clone a .git repository for one of my projects in Zend Studio 11, and now every time I switch branches in the repository, I get an error in Zend telling me `"An internal error occurred during: Detecting Library Folders".`

It seems as though one of the Zend settings files has been deleted or something.

Any idea how to restore this file, or fix this error?

```
An internal error occurred during: "Detecting library folders".
Preference node "org.eclipse.wst.validation" has been removed.
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the solution. As it turns out I was on the right track. Zend creates a hidden folder called `.settings` when you create a project.

For some reason, although it was included in the `.gitignore` file, it was deleted when switching between branches and resetting the base at one time.

I had tried removing the entire database and re-cloning earlier but that did not work. The reason was due to the `.project` (also Zend created project file) file being committed into the repository, and when re-cloned, Zend saw that file and assumed it was an existing project.

I had to remove the `.project` file completely as well.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up deleting the project from zend and re-creating it. It solved the problem.